# JavaFX Compilation Warning - "uses unchecked or unsafe operations" - Raw Data Types?

Tags: java, javafx, compiler-warnings

I am learning JavaFX, specifically trying to implement a table using the TableColumn and TableView classes. My program compiles without error, but I get an ominous-looking warning at compilation time:

```
C:\JavaFX_Sandbox>javac robotApp.java
Note: robotApp.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

C:\JavaFX_Sandbox>
```

This sufficiently weirded me out enough that I haven't had the nerve to try actually running my program. I did some digging here on StackOverflow plus a number of other sites, and discover that the most likely cause of this warning is that I'm using raw data types. But if so, I can't spot them. And if not, I'm worried what this message could mean.

To describe my program as quickly as possible: I've created a nerdy robot.java class:

```
public class robot{

    private String name;
    private int intelligence;

    public robot(String a, int b){
        this.name = a;
        this.intelligence = b;
    }
}
```

Nothing fancy. To store all those robots, I created a robotMgr.java class, essentially a glorified ArrayList to hold them all:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javafx.collections.*;

public class robotMgr{

    private ArrayList<robot> robotList;
    private ObservableList<robot> oRobotList;

    robotMgr(){
        robotList = new ArrayList<robot>();
        robotList.add(new robot("R2-D2", 7));
        robotList.add(new robot("Cylon", 3));
        robotList.add(new robot("The Terminator", 5));
        robotList.add(new robot("WALL-E", 6));
        populateOList();
    }
    public void populateOList(){
        for(int i=0; i<robotList.size(); i++)
            oRobotList.add(robotList.get(i));
    }

    public List<robot> getRobotList(){
        return robotList;
    }
    public ObservableList<robot> getORobotList(){
        return oRobotList;
    }
}
```

(I do more data manipulation in the ArrayList, but the ObservableList is necessary because the TableColumn class expects to be fed the table elements from an ObservableList.)

Now for the Main Event: A JavaFX program which takes the data above and displays it in a simple, two-column table:

```
import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.stage.*;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.*;
import javafx.event.*;
import javafx.geometry.*;
import javafx.collections.*;

public class robotApp extends Application{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch(args);   
    }

    TableColumn<robot, String> colName;
    TableColumn<robot, Integer> colIntelligenge;
    TableView<robot> robotTable;

    BorderPane borderPane;
    Scene scene;
    Stage stage;

   @Override public void start(Stage primaryStage){

        robotMgr myBots = new robotMgr();

        colName = new TableColumn<robot, String>("Name");
        colName.setMinWidth(100);
        colName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<robot, String>("Name"));
        colIntelligenge = new TableColumn<robot, Integer>("Intelligence");
        colIntelligenge.setMinWidth(100);
        colIntelligenge.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<robot, Integer>("Intelligence"));

        robotTable = new TableView<robot>();
        robotTable.getColumns().addAll(colName, colIntelligenge);
        robotTable.setItems(myBots.getORobotList());

        borderPane = new BorderPane();
        borderPane.setCenter(robotTable);
        scene = new Scene(borderPane, 600, 600);
        stage = primaryStage;
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("Robot App");
        stage.show();

    }
}
```

All looks good to me. And everything compiles fine, except for the warning messages I mentioned above. The weird thing is, the message goes away if I comment out the "robotTable.getColumns().addAll(colName, colIntelligenge);" line only.

So... I'm completely baffled. If the error message is warning me about using raw data types, I don't know where they are in my program. And if the error message is warning about something else, I don't know what that might be. Also: why would the addAll() method be the line that causes the warning? I can't figure that one out for the life for me.

Is the issue that the robots' instance variables are all private? If so, wouldn't it create a specific syntax error at compilation time?  Or is the ObservableList the problem?  In understand that OLs are interfaces, not data structures... but I don't see how this could trip me up here.

If anyone can offer some help or advice, I will be incredibly grateful.

Many thanks! -RAO

Comment: So did you try compiling with `-Xlint:unchecked` as the compiler warning said to?

Comment: (I would *strongly* urge you to start following Java naming conventions, btw - your classes should be called `Robot`, `RobotManager` and `RobotApp`.)

Comment: Link for [Java naming conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java)

Comment: You're right, Jon, I need to adopt proper naming conventions.  Believe it or not, but I used to be much worse.  I'm gradually assimiliating the conventions, its taking me a few months...  Thx for the feedback!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code is perfectly safe to run (it has bugs, which you'll discover when you run it, but those are unrelated to the typesafety about which you're asking).

Basically, the issue is that the `addAll()` method you are invoking takes a "varargs" parameter whose type is a generic type. For a `TableView<S>`, `TableView.getColumns()` returns an `ObservableList<TableColumn<S,?>>` and the `ObservableList<E>` `addAll()` method you are then calling takes a vararg parameter: `addAll(E... elements)`. So you end up calling a method with signature `addAll(TableColumn<Robot, ?>... columns)`.

Varargs are processed by converting them to an array, so you implicitly create an array of type `TableColumn<Robot, ?>[]` when you call the `addAll` method. Because arrays and parameterized types do not play well together, the compiler is unable to ensure the type safety of this array. Consequently, it issues a warning. See, e.g. [here](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6227971) for an example of why the compiler can't ensure type safety here.

The authors of the `addAll()` method probably should have coded it so that it ensured type safety and annotated it so that it avoided this warning (if that's possible: I'd need to think about it for more time than I have right now).

To avoid the warning, you can simply invoke the `add` method twice:

```
robotTable.getColumns().add(colName);
robotTable.getColumns().add(colIntelligenge);
```

Alternatively you can create a `List` of table columns and pass that to the (other) `addAll(...)` method that takes a collection, instead of a varargs parameter:

```
robotTable.getColumns().addAll(Arrays.asList(colName, colIntelligence));
```

Comment: WOW - thanks for this, there is a lot of detail for me to dig through - and, more importantly, read up on!  This is incredibly helpful, you have no idea.  :)

Comment: If you want an absolutely complete understanding of generics, I recommend "Java Generics and Collections" by Naftalin and Wadler.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue with column sorting:

```
/* avoid warning with Arrays.asList */
    tableView.getSortOrder().setAll(Arrays.asList(columnTitle));
```

Additive note, because there is no compiler hint about:
TableCell constructions.
For example, if instead of a primitive type, an Object is defined in the column as FactoryValue to be able to display an image and text in a single column cell, then make sure that the Observable Object Class implements Comparable or Comparator interface and compare the object's with the corresponding method by use of getValueSafe() on values that can be null. Otherwise an exception occurs and sorting may not work correctly.

```
/* modified column cell layout for column title */
columnTitle.setCellValueFactory(c -> new SimpleObjectProperty<AbstractNodeItem>(c.getValue()));

    columnTitle.setCellFactory(col -> {
        TableCell<AbstractNodeItem, AbstractNodeItem> cell = new TableCell<>();

        cell.itemProperty().addListener((observableValue, oldLink, newLink) -> {
            if (newLink != null) {
                Node graphic = newLink.getIconImageView();
                cell.graphicProperty().bind(Bindings.when(cell.emptyProperty()).then((Node) null).otherwise(graphic));
                cell.textProperty().bind(Bindings.when(cell.emptyProperty()).then((String) null).otherwise(newLink.propertyTitle()));

                if (!cell.getStyleClass().contains("cell-title")) {
                    cell.getStyleClass().add("cell-title");
                }
            }
        });
        return cell;
    });
```

Implementation:

```
class AbstractNodeItem implements Comparable<AbstractNodeItem>{
    public int compareTo(AbstractNodeItem o) {
        return this.propertyTitle.getValueSafe().compareTo(o.propertyTitle.getValueSafe());
    }
```

Now it is safe to sort the column!

```
    private void sortTableItems() {
        switch (SortOrder.get()) {

            case ID :
                columnIndex.setSortType(TableColumn.SortType.ASCENDING);
                tableView.getSortOrder().setAll(Arrays.asList(columnIndex));
                break;
            case TITLE :
                columnTitle.setSortType(TableColumn.SortType.ASCENDING);
                tableView.getSortOrder().setAll(Arrays.asList(columnTitle));
                break;

        }
    }
}
```